# pycharm unresolved reference on new file added to Django Project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I added a new python file named `chartcall.py` into my django (1.11.1) project in Pycharm 2017.1.3, Python 3.6. 
When I import this new file into my `views.py` I get an unresolved reference on the import.  This is only happening with the scripts I created.  chartcall does run when I debug it. Thanks ahead of time for the input.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import chartcall
    def home(request):
        orders, dollars = orders_by_day()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {orders, dollars})
```

Comment: I added them in my INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py but the issue continued.

Comment: Try the answer to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011169/python-pycharm-file-structure-issue-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-at/44011485#44011485).

Comment: This worked!! Thanks a bunch for your help, what a weird quirk!

Comment: No problem. I am flagging to close this question, however, since it is the same problem as another question.

Answer (score 0):

If file chartcall.py in the same directory with views.py, so try to

```
import .chartcall
```

or `from .chartcall import *`